# The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, int

Tags: java, android, eclipse, camera

Eclipse show me error `The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, int` what`s going wrong here and how to fix this? I must use this code to fix front camera upside-down issue in Android 4.

```
public static Bitmap createRotatedBitmap(Bitmap bm, float degree) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    if (degree != 0) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.preRotate(degree);

        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>13 && Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
        {
            float[] mirrorY = { -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1};
            matrix = new Matrix();
            Matrix matrixMirrorY = new Matrix();
            matrixMirrorY.setValues(mirrorY);

            matrix.postConcat(matrixMirrorY);

            matrix.preRotate(270);

        }

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: is the value Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT surely a boolean??

Comment: [CAMERA_FACING_FRONT is an int](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html#CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)

Comment: Please note: typically java compiler warnings tell you **all** you need to know to fix them. In your case it says "operator &&" is not defined for arguments boolean + int. The only possible conclusion: one of the two arguments must not be a boolean value; but an int. I wholeheartedly recommend to study the compiler messages carefully ... or do you intend to write up a new question here for any compiler warning that comes up?

Comment: @Jägermeister sorry, but every start is hard and I just want to learn how to make great apps. Every day I spend 8-10 hours on learning so please don't judge me, because I must deal with poor English knowledge so one reason more why I'm asking here. In books and tutorials is everything complicated for begginer.

Comment: @Karnak I am not judging. I am just telling you that your strategy has its downsides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT is a int-value and you can use logical operators as && only with booleans

Try to use Camera.CameraInfo.facing.equals(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)

Answer (score 1):

Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT is an int, so what you're essentially trying to do is

```
if (true && 1) ...
```

Read the documentation of Camera more carefully to find out how to use it properly. You need to call "getNumberOfCameras" and then "getCameraInfo" for each id returned.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem.hopefully i was able to resolve it.see first of all its a compilation issue.the && operator in java requires boolean expressions/values to operate upon.note:all the operands must be of boolean type.now coming to your question.in the following line:
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>13 &&Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
(*android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>13*) is an boolean expression and it results to either true or false but (*Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT*) in an int type so compiler is giving the issue.to fix this try to give a boolean expression in the second argument instead of directly giving a int type value   and the problem will go away.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).